# I tried creating a cookbook in chef but why this is showing this error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, chef-infra

I have installed chef in AWS EC2 instance. After installing I run the command `chef generate cookbook test-cookbook` and it is showing this error /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/bin/ruby: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I tried re-installing. I also tried creating a new instance and repeat the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Error:

```
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/bin/ruby: error while loading shared libraries: 
libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Use this command to fix this problem:

```
yum install libxcrypt-compat
```

This command has also worked for me. This command has
worked for AWS EC2 (amazon linux machine).

Answer (score 0):

"yum install libxcrypt-compat" cmd worked for me. You can try this once.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i resolved it.

If you face this error while running command

```
# chef generate cookbook my_cookbook
```

> ```
> exit status 127 /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/bin/ruby: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypt.so.1: cannot open shared
> ```
>
> object file: No such file or directory

this means your `libcrypt.so.1` is probably missing. You can install all pacakges in Linux/AWS/Redhat by,

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install glibc
```

Now search for library

```
find / -name "libcrypt.so.1" 2>/dev/null
```

If the find command shows nothing, this means "*libcrypt.so.1*" is still missing. Download and install it manually by,

```
yum provides "*/libcrypt.so.1"
yum install "*/libcrypt.so.1"
```

Now search again, it would show paths to the library.

```
find / -name "libcrypt.so.1" 2>/dev/null
```

Run the chef generate command now, it would be working most probably.

```
# chef generate cookbook my_cookbook
```